# CSS coding issues in nav menu

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have 2 issues I wanted to resolve in a CSS menu I'm coding but I find it out of my reach to handle them. Before I put the code here let me describe my 2 issues:
1) I'd like to have the all li area clickable instead of only the text..
2) I think the image and text is not correctly alingned vertically and wanted to fix that also.

Also: You can see the code I have in action at www.nfrases.com/modelo.php

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div class="drop-menu">
     <span class="plus">+</span><span class="droptexto">Navegação</span>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.pt"><img src="/images/icon_info.png" alt="rss"> Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.pt"><img src="/images/icon_email.png" alt="rss"> Contactos</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav { width: 640px; float: right; }
.drop-menu { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; display: block; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 10px 10px; font-size: 22px; height: 30px; max-height: 30px; width: 120px; cursor: pointer; border-left: 1px solid #e7e4d4; border-right: 1px solid #e7e4d4; background: url("../images/bg_header.png") repeat scroll right top transparent; float: right; }
.drop-menu a, .drop-menu  a:visited { color: #464530; text-decoration: none; }
.drop-menu a:hover { color:#ff5400; }
.drop-menu span.droptexto { padding-left:10px; font-size: 20px; color: #ff5400; font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive; }
.plus { display: inline-block; -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out; color: #ff5400; }
.drop-menu:hover .plus { -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); -o-transform: rotate(45deg); }
.drop-menu:hover { border-left: 1px solid #e7e4d4; border-right: 1px solid #e7e4d4; }
.drop-menu:hover .sub-menu { display: inline-block; }
.sub-menu { display: none; width: 120px; background: #fff; padding: 10px 10px; margin-left: -11px; margin-top: 12px; border: 1px solid #e7e4d4; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 25px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2); }
.sub-menu li { list-style-type: none; display: block; border: 1px; border-color: #fff; border-style: dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted #eaeaea; font-size: 19px; height: 24px; padding: 8px 0; font-size: 12px; }
.sub-menu li img { margin-right: .5em; margin-left: .5em; }
.sub-menu li:hover { border: 1px; border-color: #ff5400; border-style: dotted; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested earlier to make complete link clickable use  `display:block` and define width&height or padding

```
.sub-menu li a {display:block; padding: 10px;}
```

to make the image and text aligned to center, the best approach is to put the image in background either li's or 'a' tag's.  Dont forget the padding-left shd be greater than the width of the image.

```
.sub-menu li a.img1 { background-image:url(images/imagename.jpg); }

.sub-menu li a { background-position:center left; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; display: block; padding-left: 20px; }
```

Even if u dont want to put the image in background then try  this. It may work. Set the height as per the height of the image, or use padding.

```
.sub-menu li a { height: 20px; line-height:20px; display: block;}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
.drop-menu a {
    display:block;
   }
```

2) Add the left image as background image of `<li>` then you can center the image and text horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/YGHNu/

To make a full link set a to "display: block;", then set height and margin. To center image use "vertical-align: middle", and then move it a little higher with margin-top.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, I didn't knew jsfiddle! Thanks fot that also!